# Create unique alpha numeric string for an input string/url?

Tags: php

I want to create a less than or equal to 10 character unique string for an input string which could be a url

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

OR an alpha numeric string

```
programming124
```

but the result should be unique for every input...Is their any function or class that you use for your projects in php... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a unique and random string, you can use the following function to create a random string:

```
function randString($length) {
    $charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $str = '';
    while ($length-- > 0) {
        $str .= $charset[rand() % 62];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

After you have generated a new string, look up your database if that string already exists. If so, repeat that step until you’ve generated a unique string. Then store that new string in the database:

```
do {
    $randString = randString(10);
    // look up your database if $randString already exists and store the result in $exists
} while ($exists);
// store new random string in database
```

Comment: how can I create a simple lookup table? Thanks for the quick response Gumbo

Comment: @halocursed: You could use a SQL database.

Comment: Gumbo I am actually saving id identifier for users on my website so they can login using email or openid so should I just use an auto increment(for id column) in the database while adding user info...or should I create unique identifier for every user using your method...which one is better?

Comment: @halocursed: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you want to create some kind of short URL service. What you need is both a unique and random string. Using a auto-incremeted value doesn’t fulfill the latter criterion of randomness since the values are absolutely predictable.

Comment: @halocursed: Use an arbitrary random generator and test if that ID already exists. Simply search for *php random string* for the random generator and use a database to store your already generated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest function available in php is [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid). It is a little longer that you had mentioned, and wont work well with load balancing, but if you are doing something super simple, it should work alright.